# Error while building a network graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

File "C:/Users/Vrushab PC/Downloads/Dissertation/untitled0.py", line 125, in

matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (50, 50)

NameError: name 'matplotlib' is not defined

I have imported matplotlib.pyplot but still getting this? what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (50, 50)
```

From matplotlib [docs](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

You are importing pyplot framework from matplotlib(a part of matplotlib), you don't have access to the full matplotlib library until you do the above import as mpl. Now, you can use mpl alias to access rcParams.